# Activity/Fragment to Activity/Fragment to Activity/Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Looking for a best practices solution to this issue.

Activity1 contains Fragment1 with a spinner of valid products

Activity1 contains an action bar menu option 'products' which launches Activity2 containing Fragment2 (list fragment).

From Fragment2 you can add/edit products using Activity3/Fragment3.

Changes made in Fragment3 I am getting back to Fragment2 with ActivityResult, and I know I could also achieve the same with an Interface.

The question is:  What is the best way to get changes made in Fragment 3 reflected in the Fragment1 spinner?

I know I could reload the spinner values in Fragment1 in onResume() but if I didn't make any changes in Fragment3 this would be unnecessary.

Comment: ContentProvider + Loaders will do this for you :)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, trying to avoid this as its more complicated than I need.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an Observer pattern. Implement an Interface with something like

```
public void onInputChanged(yourStuff);
```

let your first Fragment implement this Interface and Add the Fragment to a Listener Pool.

and from your Activity where the change happened, do something like

```
EventManager.fireOnInPutChanged(yourData)
```

EventManager would b the calls your listeners sign up to.

like this you wont need Activity forResult and you always know if something has changed.

Comment: Thanks for this response but don't know enough to implement it.  Can you point me to an example?